# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lorg.drools.rule.Package; cannot be cast to org.drools.rule.Package

Tags: drools-guvnor

i have this problem when trying to access Guvnor model.
Here the code:

```
RuleAgent ruleAgent = RuleAgent.newRuleAgent("/guvnor.properties");
RuleBase ruleBase = ruleAgent.getRuleBase();
FactType factype = ruleBase.getFactType("sample.Number");
Object obj = factype.newInstance();
factype.set(obj, "numberOne", 1);
factype.set(obj, "numberTwo", 1);
WorkingMemory workingMemory = ruleBase.newStatefulSession();
workingMemory.insert(obj);
workingMemory.fireAllRules();
System.out.println(factype.get(obj, "message"));
```

The problem appear executing this line: RuleBase ruleBase = ruleAgent.getRuleBase();
and return me this exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lorg.drools.rule.Package; cannot be cast to org.drools.rule.Package

### This is my configuration:

jboss-eap-6.1

### guvnor-5.5.0.Final-jboss-as-7.0.war

my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.drools</groupId>
<artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
<version>5.5.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.drools</groupId>
<artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
<version>5.5.0.Final</version>
```

Have somebody solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am using drools version 5.4 ,This is common bug in guvnor 5.4 .I guess this issue is fixed in drools version 5.5.0.Beta1 ,

Please check 
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3590

Regards
Ganesh N
ganeshneelekani@gmail.com